# Sporadic JSONDecodeError during API Request

Tags: python, json, api

I am creating a simple program that takes the 'last' value from Bitstamp.net API and uses it. See code below.

```
def getBitcoinPrice():

    url = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")
        os.system('say "The program broke."')
```

I will get sporadic JSONDecodeError sometimes after 3 minutes, other times after several hours. I have looked everywhere and can't figure this out. See the error below. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
File "/Users/paulkaraffa/PycharmProjects/socialbitanalytics/actionEvaluator.py", line 70, in <module>
    btcValues.append(getBitcoinPrice())

File "/Users/paulkaraffa/PycharmProjects/socialbitanalytics/actionEvaluator.py", line 26, in getBitcoinPrice
    priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: suggestion solution**

```
def getBitcoinPrice():

    url = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=60)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        # wait 5 seconds and try again. This would require you to put your try block 
        # into it's own function so you can more easily call it here in the exception.
    else:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")
        os.system('say "The program broke."')
```

**Original Answer**

When you say you get the error after 3 minutes or several hours, you mean that the code runs, waits for 3 minutes or several hours, and then throws the error? That sounds like a timeout issue, which means if a URL doesn't respond within X seconds it will return a 504 error, though I would expect it to be a consistent 60 seconds or 180 seconds. I recommend using Postman to make requests and see the response on an error. Or better would be to print out the error in your current code, or enter into a pdb.set_trace() on error.

The error you're getting is because `requests.get(url)` fails, which means `r.text` is `None`, which causes your `priceFloat` line to error. In other words, the last line in your stack trace, `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None...` means that `json.loads()` is being passed `None` instead of a value.

As a rule of thumb, if you get an error but not all the time, it's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which is 'where the output is dependent on the sequence or timing of other uncontrollable events. It becomes a bug when events do not happen in the order the programmer intended.'

Comment: Thanks for the info. The code grabs the current value from the API and then stores it in a list variable. It does this every 5 seconds. The program will run grabbing new values every 5 seconds and adding them but then it will crash sometimes with this error. So, it does not seem like a timeout issue. I was thinking it might an issue with the website but the values show up fine every time I check the ticker.

Comment: In your `except` clause, print the value of `r`, and the response you're getting from the API. The response is going to be a HTML code of 400 or higher (400s are client errors and 500s are server errors), most likely.

You could also use Selenium to grab a screenshot on error. See [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608768/perform-a-screenshot-upon-an-exception) for more info.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'll do that now and then see what I get when I run it.

Comment: Jason, I tried an except clause and got <Response 200> while it was running. It was also the last HTML code I received. So everything seemed to be working when it broke.

Comment: What was the value of `r` when you got the `JSONDecodeError`?

Comment: The value of r was set at 200. I've had it break several times but it always shows r as 200.

Comment: I've been been toying with this idea. Can't you just find a way to say "if r does not connect, then try again"? I'm wondering now if this isn't an issue with the internet or their output. Either way, it starts working again right after I restart the program. Wondering if this would fix the problem. I tried creating an if statement for this but it did not work...

Comment: You can do an exception that is specific to the JSONDecodeError, and in that except clause just retry. Not the best solution, but it should work until you or they can figure out the real issue.

Comment: Oh nice. Thanks, Jason!

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with a fix, though I'm not sure it is the most elegant fix. Jason was correct that it was a timeout error. I changed the following code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

to

```
r = requests.get(url, timeout=120.0)
```

By making this change the error was mostly gone. However, I needed to add code to the except clause that would still fill this value. To do this I added a separate request.get before defining getBitcoinPrice() which gave me a value for this situation. Code looks like this:

```
urlException = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
r = requests.get(urlException, timeout=600.0)
exceptionValue = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
print(exceptionValue)

def getBitcoinPrice():
    url = 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/'
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=120.0)
        priceFloat = float(json.loads(r.text)['last'])
        return priceFloat

    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Error querying Bitstamp API")
        return exceptionValue
```

If someone has a more elegant solution, let me know! :)

Comment: See my original answer, I've updated it with my suggestion.